# Grouped bar chart time series in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart, data-analysis

I have a **csv file** in the format shown below.

[image]

I would like to plot a **grouped bar chart**, where the four values (one for each of the four columns like great_deal, only_some, etc) for a **given year are grouped** next to each other in a time series. However, when I run the code below, it displays a "stacked" and not grouped bar chart. Does anyone know how I might write the correct code for such a grouped bar chart using **ggplot2**?

```
ggplot(confinan)+
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=year, y=great_deal, fill="blue"), stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=year, y=dont_know, fill="red"), stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Comment: `confinan |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-year) |> ggplot(aes(year, value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = position_dodge())`. You might insert a step just before the ggplot like `dplyr::mutate(name = forcats::fct_inorder(name)) |>` to keep the ordering from the original table columns as an ordered factor, lest ggplot2 show them ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your desired chart by doing a `pivot_longer()` thrown in before the `ggplot` like so

```
confinan %>% select(everything()) %>%
    pivot_longer(.,
        cols=c(great_deal,only_some,hardly_any,dont_know),
        names_to="Var",
        values_to="Val") %>%
    ggplot(aes(y=Val,x=year,fill=Var))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```